Get error provider.getSigner() is not function when calling hook in d-apps
I have a hook like that
export const useERC20 = (address: string, chainId: number) => {
  const { provider } = useActiveWeb3React(chainId)
  return useMemo(
    () => address && getErc20Contract(address, provider?.getSigner()),
    [address, provider],
  )
}

if i use this hook in other hook, it will be fine in metamask (web). But it get error provider?.getSigner is not a function when i call this func in D-app. What is the point issues here? Thanks.
the code i call other hook
export default function useSendTokenTest({ tokenContract, chainId }) {
  const { switchNetwork } = useSwitchNetwork()
  const { account: signerAddress } = useActiveWeb3React(chainId)
  const tokenUseContract = useERC20(tokenContract, chainId)
  const sendTokenTest = useCallback(
    async ({ address }) => {
      try {
        await switchNetwork(chainId)
        const doTransaction = await tokenUseContract.transfer(
          address,
          new BigNumber(Math.pow(10, 18)).toFixed(),
        )
        const response = await doTransaction.wait()
        console.log("RESPONSE:========: ", JSON.stringify(response))
        toast.info(`ERRRORRRR==========: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("ERRRORRRR==========:", JSON.stringify(error))
        toast.error(`ERRRORRRR==========: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
      }
    },
    [chainId, signerAddress, tokenUseContract],
  )
  return { sendTokenTest }
}

Anyone can help me? Thanks
